# Service Fabric Stateful Service Replica memory spiked without any activity

Tags: memory-leaks, heap-memory, azure-service-fabric, windbg, stateful-actor-service

One of the replicas of the below-mentioned node started taking 82 MB and spiked up to 172 MB suddenly without any activity on the service. The dump says there are objects due to service fabric.

We are using:

1. Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Runtime V9.1.1390.9590
2. Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK V6.1.13909590

node : Backend_1

172mb heap dump:

```
00007ffbe2a85ee8       19       207848 Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LogRecord\
00007ffbe2b893e0     5893       235720 Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.TransactionStateMachine
00007ffc3f470e70     5913       236520 System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch
00007ffc40667e00     2325       260400 System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo
00007ffc3ff53758     7324       292960 System.Collections.Generic.List System.Object, mscorlib 
00007ffc40622978       28       293704 System.Int64 
00007ffc4066c088     4223       318520 System.Int32[] 
00007ffbe2bd3498     4731       378480 Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LogManager+FlushAsync 
00007ffbe2aab6d8    17365       416760 System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource System.Boolean, mscorlib
00007ffbe2bf8250    11774       470960 Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.OperationData2
00007ffbe2b895b8    11786       471440 System.Collections.Generic.List Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LockContext, Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Impl 
00007ffbe2ae76c0     4731       492024 Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.PhysicalLogWriter+<FlushAsync> 
00007ffc41131ea8     7766       497024 System.Action System.Threading.Tasks.Task System.Boolean, mscorlib, mscorlib 
00007ffbe2aab490     7766       497024 System.Func System.Threading.Tasks.Task, mscorlib,[System.Threading.Tasks.Task, mscorlib
00007ffbe2bf67f8    17363       555616 Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.SecondaryDrainManager DisplayClass30_2
00007ffbe2aab258    17366       555712 System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection System.ArraySegment System.Byte mscorlib, mscorlib
00007ffc406612c8    17413       557216 System.ComObject
00007ffbe2ae7870     7766       559152 Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.LogRecord AwaitFlushd
00007ffbe24c0b78     1649       561408 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary Entry Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty Newtonsoft.Json Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader+PropertyPresence, Newtonsoft.Json 
00007ffbe2b88ce8     5893       612872 Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.Transaction 
00007ffc411a9018     7766       621280 System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask System.Boolean mscorlib
00007ffc40669e18     8362       667720 System.Object
00007ffbe2aab890     7766       683408 System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromTask System.Threading.Tasks.Task mscorlib 
00007ffbe2b87c20    17368       694720 System.Fabric.OperationData 
00007ffbe2bf92a0    10714       857120 Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.SecondaryDrainManager DisplayClass30 DrainCopyStreamAsync 
00007ffbe2bf6910    17364       972384 Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Replicator.SecondaryDrainManager DisplayClass30 
00007ffbe2bf7be8    11571      1018248
```

We have tried to change the Service Fabric Cluster settings but didn't see any improvement.

We would like to know why Service Fabric Stateful Service Replica memory spiked without any activity.